# How to avoid excessive empty space at the end of a line using a Text component in React-native?

Tags: react-native

I'm using the `Text` component of `React-native` with the `numberOfLines={2}` and `adjustsFontSizeToFit` props, but I'm having some trouble addressing the issue of excessive blank space at the end of lines (excluding the final line).

I'll provide some examples to help illustrate my problem.

When I insert a text like the one shown in the below screenshot, with the final word only 3 characters long, there is a lot of empty space on the first line.
[image]

However, when the last word is 4 characters long, the text is arranged on two lines without leaving too much empty space on the first line:
[image]

I think this is because in this case the text would goes onto 3 lines, and so it reduces the font size to accomodate it on 2 lines.

My question is: How can I consistently replicate the second scenario, thereby reducing the excessive empty space at the end of each line?

Here is the snack link, but you should use a device to see the described effect.
https://snack.expo.dev/hffxm4MXL